# git clone does not work when directory not empty

Tags: git, unix

I want to do git clone repo/branch_tag .
this command don't work because current directory not empty.
this directory contain only one script:

```
git clone repo/branch_tag .
```

How can I do it ?
can I do "`git reset --hard tagname`" after move to . ? I can't remove script because it invoke this commands.

Comment: Don't use . - use some other name: `git clone repo/branch_tag foo`.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: can I do "git reset --hard tagname" after move to . ? I can't remove script because it invoke this commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can either remove that script or create the repo on a separate directory and then move the content into the desired one, not forget to add your .git folder when you do this.

Hope it helps

Ps. If you remove the script you can paste it once the repo is fully cloned

Comment: can I do "git reset --hard tagname" after move to . ? I can't remove script because it invoke this commands.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough, you can copy the script (Ctrl +X) and after you are done with the cloning process, you paste it again in the same directory (Ctrl+V). This will produce that your `git status` will show you an non tracked file (your script), then you just need to add it to your stage area ande then commit it. Or if you don't want it in your repo, add it to your `.gitignore` file,